# Create new friend list on Facebook

Tags: facebook

With the Facebook Android app I can add and remove friends from existing friend lists but I cannot find a way to create a new list.

Am I missing something? If not, is there an app available that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Facebook app does not have this feature (and several other features that are available on the web app). However, you can create a new list with a 3rd-party app like Fast Pro for Facebook.

[image]